# Do I have -3823 rep change?

Tags: bug, reputation

Currently my user page https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5133/curiousguy?tab=reputation contains:

```
<a class="youarehere" href="/users/5133/curiousguy?tab=reputation" title="reputation you have earned" data-shortcut="R">
                        <span class='bounty-indicator-tab'>-3823</span>
                    Reputation
                </a>
```

**-3823** is the largest absolute reputation change I have seen. I am *not* worried, my reputation graph seems to be mostly monotonic, but that is odd!

(I don't consult that user page often as I use the message box to see replies and events.)

I have seen only one "User was removed" event:

> -10    May 14
>
> -10   21:03   removed User was removed (learn more)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? What rep do you think it is supposed to be?

Comment: @schroeder Reputation is correct it's the value on the button with the link https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5133/curiousguy?tab=reputation that was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that you were at rank change, but your code snippet shows something else. This appears to be a bug that's currently unsolved. It seems to not actually touch your reputation, see [Where has my 24922 rep gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350734/where-has-my-24922-rep-gone) at the SEmeta site.